# Adding a class to an ICollection List

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I have a C# project in which users can log in and create boards. The user class has an ICollection for listing all the boards made by a specific user and I am trying to figure out how to add that board to the list.

These are the two classes, the User class:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Board> Boards { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

And this is the Board class:

```
public class Board
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

The aim is that each User would have a list of all the boards that have been added they have created so it is necessary for the board to be added to that list when it is created. This the webform where a board can be added:

```
public partial class AddBoard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Board boardToAdd = new Board();
    User user = new User();
    Utility utility = new Utility();

    static User loggedInUser;


    protected void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = NameTextBox.Text;
        loggedInUser = (User)Session["loggedInUser"];

        string checkName = utility.CheckBoardName(name);
        if (checkName == "OK")
        {
            boardToAdd.Name = name;
            boardToAdd.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            user.AddBoard(boardToAdd, loggedInUser);
            boardToAdd.AddBoard(boardToAdd);


        }
        else
        {
            CreateLabel.Text = checkName;
        }
    }
```

And this is the method in the user class I've been trying to use to add the board to the list:

```
public User AddBoard(Board board, User user)
    {
        BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
        user.Boards.Add(board);
        return null;

    }
}
```

For added reference this is the method in the board class I am calling in order to add the board:

```
public bool AddBoard(Board board)
    {
        BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
        try
        {
            _context.Boards.Add(board);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what **is** the problem?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. No error is occurring, but the board isn't being added to the list, so there is no record of which user created the board.

Answer (score 0):

In your AddBoard, you are adding to a local variable.

After function exit, this is destroyed.

Promote your _context to a class member

Comment: Thanks, does that involving stating the 'BulletinContext _context' outside of the methods, because that is already the case?

Answer (score 0):

As Pieter21 said, the variable `_context` in `Board.AddBoard()` is recreated each time you call `Board.AddBoard()`. As far as I can see, `_context` should be static and declared outside of the `AddBoard()` method (since you probably need to access it later).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort out the problem. I just added in code to my method to call the user that the board was being added to and the board to be added.It now looks like this:

```
public User AddBoard(Board board, User user)
    {
        BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
        User _user = _context.Users.Find(user.ID);
        Board _board = _context.Boards.Find(board.ID);
        _user.Boards.Add(_board);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return null;

    }
```

It's necessary to call this method from the other method that adds the board to the Board class so that it occurs afterwards.